# Permissions for portal owners are not working

Tags: 2013, permissions

We have issue where we want to grant permission to user to be able to edit content on any SharePoint site. We have added user to "Portal owners" group which should be anyone who can edit anything, but nothing happens. What we have also discovered this user belongs to group "it_department", so when we add "it_department" under portal owners (instead of just user) it works, but then it affects more users then it should. Any idea how to resolve permission issues?

We use SharePoint 2013, Windows server 2012 R2 for front-end and central admin, MSSQL server 2012, ADFS for authentication, Configuration database version: 15.0.4763.1000

Comment: Can you confirm if there are custom permission levels set up for the group ?  Compare the permission levels of portal owners and it_department group ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using inherited permissions. Check the list you are talking about has unique permissions and if that is the case add the `Portal Owners` group into that.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your answer. "Portal owners" group has access to everything, why adding user won't work, but adding group that has that user would?